# System process: high virtual memory usage

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, virtual-memory

Azure virtual machine (3,5 Gb) with Server2012 running 2 IIS8 sites.

At some time after reboot, System (pid 4) Private Virtual Memory reaches limit (15 Gb) with 2004 event: `Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: System (4) consumed 12292460544 bytes, w3wp.exe (4832) consumed 460812288 bytes, and w3wp.exe (2248) consumed 439529472 bytes.`
Working set around 100 Mb.

`IISreset` does not help, only machine rebooting.

[process explorer Performance tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpXRn.png)

Do you have any idea want to do?

Comment: Based on your information above it seems the system process is using most of the virtual memory. I'd suggest using something like process explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to dig a bit more into what in the system process is using it.

Comment: Only Interrupts and smss.exe under System process.

Comment: And which one is using more memory?

Comment: interrupts 0, smss 272k. And there is no way to dump system process memory?